# Getting a return value from axios function in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am new to reactJS , my problem is that I want to assign my varaiable a value that has been returned from a axios function.When I do this, I get undefined value for u1.

```
 function getUsername(userid){
        var user = ''
        axios.post('/api/getuserdata' , {_id:userid}).then(res=>{
            console.log(res.data)
            const userdata = res.data[0]
            user = userdata.username

        }).catch(err=>{
            console.log(err)
        })

        return user

    }
    const u1 = getUsername(id)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code doesn't work is that the `POST` request handled by `axios` is async, your `getUsername` function won't wait for that request to resolve and return `user` immediately after it's called.
The simplest solution is that make your `getUsername` async and call it in another async function, or if you want to use the result returned from `POST` request for some other stuff, you can store it as `state` in `React`, it would be better.
You can use something like this:

```
const getUsername = async (userid) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post("/api/getuserdata", { _id: userid });
        const userdata = response?.data?.[0]?.username || "";
        return userdata;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`error`, error);
    }
};

// in another function
const doSomethingWithUsername = async (id) => {
    const username = await getUsername(id);
    // other stuff..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
async function getUsername(userid) {
    try {
        const result = await axios.post('/api/getuserdata' , {_id:userid});
        const user = result.data;
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```